# Convert sql query in query in Active Record in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I need to convert this query in an active Record query.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE CAST(date AS DATE) = '2017-06-19' AND `ip` = '::1'
```

this is what I tried but the `where` with the `date` does not work

```
 function search($date, $ip){
   $this->db->select('cast(date as Date)');
   $this->db->where('date', $date);
   $this->db->where('ip', $ip);
   return $this->db->get('visitas'); 
  }
```

this produce something like this

```
SELECT cast(fecha as Date) FROM (`visitas`) WHERE `ip` = '::1'
```

thank´s in advance.

Comment: Just use `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE CAST(date AS DATE) = '2017-06-19' AND `ip` = '::1'")`. [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to test this at the moment but I believe it's what you're looking for.

```
// Convert your date string to mysql datetime
$date = date( "Y-m-d" , strtotime("2017-06-19") );

// Build the query
$this->db->select('*')->from('visitas')
                      ->where('CAST(date AS DATE)=', $date)
                      ->where('ip', '::1');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: In my case I do not need the variable `$date`

Comment: I do the cast becouse I just need the date part of my date